# What does it mean for a basis set to be "correlation consistent" ?

Tags: computational-chemistry, basis-set

Some basis sets are said to be "correlation consistent". What does it mean in practice ?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has an answer here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)#Correlation-consistent_basis_sets

**Edit: adding introductory text from Wikipedia:**

> Some of the most widely used basis sets are those developed by Dunning
>   and coworkers, since they are designed to converge systematically to
>   the complete-basis-set (CBS) limit using empirical extrapolation
>   techniques. For first- and second-row atoms, the basis sets are
>   cc-pVNZ where N=D,T,Q,5,6,... (D=double, T=triples, etc.). The 'cc-p',
>   stands for 'correlation-consistent polarized' and the 'V' indicates
>   they are valence-only basis sets. They include successively larger
>   shells of polarization (correlating) functions (d, f, g, etc.). More
>   recently these 'correlation-consistent polarized' basis sets have
>   become widely used and are the current state of the art for correlated
>   or post-Hartree-Fock calculations.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't really answering the question in a physical way.  That "answer" is just a summary of the recipe used to achieve the desired physical property.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading Thom Dunning Jr. “Gaussian basis sets for use in correlated molecular calculations. I. The atoms boron through neon and hydrogen.” [J. Chem. Phys. 90, 1007 (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.456153) by for an answer to this question.

The abstract says the following:

> This leads to the concept of correlation consistent basis sets, i.e., sets which include all functions in a given group as well as all functions in any higher groups.

This refers to the telescoping nature of the angular momentum levels used,  e.g. 5s4p3d2f1g.

Comment: Updated link or full reference?

Comment: Sorry about that. I’m not used to JChP breaking links. I added the article details and used DOI link instead.